# How is Jesus "υἱὸς ὑψίστου κληθήσεται" (Luke 1:32 NAS28) different from a prophet (παιδίον, προφήτης ὑψίστου κληθήσῃ Luke 1:76 NAS28)?

Tags: jesus, prophecy

> οὗτος ἔσται μέγας καὶ **υἱὸς ὑψίστου κληθήσεται** καὶ δώσει αὐτῷ κύριος ὁ θεὸς τὸν θρόνον Δαυὶδ τοῦ πατρὸς αὐτοῦ, Luke 1:32 NAS28

> He shall be great, and shall be called the **Son of the Highest**: and the Lord God shall give unto him the throne of his father David:  Luke 1:32 KJV

> Καὶ σὺ δέ, παιδίον, **προφήτης ὑψίστου κληθήσῃ**· προπορεύσῃ γὰρ ἐνώπιον κυρίου ἑτοιμάσαι ὁδοὺς αὐτοῦ, Luke. 1:76 NAS28

> And thou, child, shalt be called the **prophet of the Highest**: for thou shalt go before the face of the Lord to prepare his ways; Luke 1:76 KJV

Comment: You have commented on both answers saying this was not what you had in mind.  May I ask what DO you have in mind?  Perhaps you could explain why you think 'Son of the Highest' is connected to and different from 'Prophet of the Highest'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first text is spoken by an angel, to the virgin Mary, regarding the One to be born of her. This One shall be called Jesus, she is told, "and he shall be great, and shall be called Son of the Highest, and the Lord God shall give unto him the throne of his father David."

The second text is spoken by Zacharias when his tongue was loosened at the birth of his son, John (the Baptist). Zacharias addressed his baby son saying (amongst other things), "And thou child, shalt be called the prophet of the Highest, for thou shalt go before the face of the Lord to prepare his ways."

"The Highest" in both texts is the same - God Almighty.

The Son in the first text is the unique, "only begotten Son of God" (not just one of many sons). His unique designation - only begotten" - shows the unique relationship of this One with Almighty God.

The prophet in the second text is one of many prophets, though his role as going before Messiah to prepare the way of this Lord is unique. However, John is but a man, who needed to come under the saving grace of God through Jesus Christ. John did not have David in earthly line of descent, as did Jesus. John, the prophet, would never be given the throne of David.

Jesus is also shown in scripture to be a prophet, by the way. (It would cast total doubt on his claim to be the foretold Messiah is he had not been a prophet!). The key point is not the word 'prophet', but that the first text speaks of the unique Son of God, while the second text speaks of a different child born, to prepare the way before the Son of God.

***The question is not how Jesus is different from a prophet (because he was a prophet, Acts 3:20-26) but how he is different from all other prophets in being the only-begotten Son of God.***

Comment: I didn't have the relationship in mind: an angel's speech versus a priest's speech.

Comment: _"John did not have David in earthly line of descent, as did Jesus."_ John and Jesus were second cousins.  Their mothers were cousins.  (See Luke 1:36.) This means John and Jesus had the same _maternal_ great-grandfather.  Zacharias, as a priest, was of the tribe of Levi.  Elisabeth was of the _daughters_ of Aaron, who would have married husbands whose tribes we are not told.  Upon what evidence can one say John was _not_ a descendant of David?

Comment: @Biblasia Yes, they were cousins. John's mother and father both descended from Aaron. The link in Jesus' genealogy with the line of Aaron was via Amminadab, who was father-in-law of Aaron, but that was not a direct blood relationship with Aaron, as far as I understand (Mat. 1:4). Connections with David and John the Baptist were different to Jesus' direct lineage to David. Their lines of descent were not the same, for Jesus was David's Lord; the kingdom was Christ's, not John the Baptists. That's was my meaning.

Comment: Anne, I don't count as of the tribe of Benjamin because my Benjamite blood is from my mother's side of the family.  Jews reckon only on the father for tribal determination.  All the same, I am a descendant of Benjamin.  You cannot know that none of Elisabeth's maternal ancestors, and none of the mothers on her paternal line, had descended from David.  I guess that is my point.  It's fine to state supportable truths; but we should avoid definitive statements where the Bible is silent.

Answer (score 2):

One answer is found in Hebrews;

"[Jesus] was faithful to him who appointed him, just as Moses also was faithful in God's house. Yet Jesus has been counted worthy of as much more glory than Moses as the builder of a house has more honour than the house... Now Moses was faithful in all God's house as a servant, to testify to the things that were to be spoken later, but Christ was over God's house as a son" (Hebrews, ch3 vv2-6, RSV).

Any prophet is only a servant in the household, part of the household. The Son is joint Master of the household.

Comment: I didn't have this answer in mind.

Answer (score 0):

"Highest" and "Most high" are epithets to designate God Almighty either directly or things that belong to Him.  Here is a brief sample.

**Epithet of God Himself:**

- Gen 14:19, 20 - “Blessed be Abram by **God Most High**, Creator of heaven and earth, And praise be to **God Most High**, who delivered your enemies into your hand."
- Num 24:16 - the prophecy of one who hears the words of **God**, who has knowledge from **the Most High**, who sees a vision from **the Almighty**, who bows down with eyes wide open:
- Deut 32:8 - When the **Most High** [God] gave the nations their inheritance, when He divided the sons of man, He set the boundaries of the peoples according to the number of the sons of God.
- Ps 47:2 - How awesome is the **LORD Most High**, the great King over all the earth!
- Ps 57:2 - I cry out to **God Most High**, to God who fulfills His purpose for me.
- Ps 83:18 - May they know that You alone, whose name is **the LORD, are Most High** over all the earth.
- Ps 92:1 - It is a good thing to give thanks unto the **LORD**, and to sing praises unto thy name, **O most High**:
- Dan 4:24 - This is the interpretation, O king, and this is the decree that the **Most High** [God] has issued against my lord the king:
- Dan 5:18 - As for you, O king, the **Most High God** gave your father Nebuchadnezzar sovereignty and greatness, glory and honor.
- Mark 5:7 - And he shouted in a loud voice, “What do You want with me, Jesus, Son of **the Most High God**? I beg You before God not to torture me!”
- Luke 1:32 - He will be great and will be called the **Son of the Most High** [God]. The Lord God will give Him the throne of His father David,
- Luke 1:76 - And you, child, will be called a **prophet of the Most High** [God]; for you will go on before the Lord to prepare the way for Him,
- Acts 7:48 - Yet the **Most High** [God] does not dwell in hand-made houses. As the prophet says:
- Heb 7:1 - This Melchizedek was king of Salem and priest of **God Most High**. He met Abraham returning from the slaughter of the kings and blessed him,

**Designation of Things belonging to God:**

- Luke 2:14 - "Glory to **God in the highest** [heaven?], and on earth peace among men with whom He is pleased!"  See also Matt 21:9
- Luke 19:38 - “Blessed is the King who comes in the name of the Lord!” “Peace in heaven and **glory in the highest**!”
- Deut 10:14 - Behold, to the LORD your God belong the heavens, even the **highest heavens**, and the earth and everything in it.
- Ps 68:33 - to Him [God] who rides upon **the highest heavens** of old; behold, His mighty voice resounds.

Thus, "most high" is a direct designation/title for God and things belonging to God such a the highest heaven, highest praise, etc.

In the particular case of Luke 1:32 & 76, we have a designation of:

- God's Son (Jesus) as "The Son of the Most High"
- God's prophet (John the Baptist) as "the prophet of the Most High".